# Rust: how to perform heavy amount of concurrency in a loop?

Tags: rust, concurrency

Supposing I have calculation like:

```
async fn sum_2(x: &f64) -> f64 {
   x + 2
}

fn main() {
   let mut x = vec![
      vec![1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
      vec![2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
   ];

   for i in 0..2 {
      for j in 0..3 {
         x[i][j] = sum_2(x[i][j]).await;
      }
   }
}
```

What is the right/better way of performing this concurrently?
I am aware of `join!()`, which is excellent when the calls are known.
I also know the `thread::spawn()`, but I don't know if this is the right tool for achieving this, nor how. Isn't there something like a pool of threads in Rust that I could send all function calls into and then execute? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the rayon crate

Comment: Could you please give an example for the code above or guide me to something similar? All examples I found are quite difficult for me to understand or a bit different since I would like to update the values in place.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're looking for [`futures::future::join_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.18/futures/future/fn.join_all.html).

From the official example:

> ```rust
> use futures::future::join_all;
> async fn foo(i: u32) -> u32 { i }
> let futures = vec![foo(1), foo(2), foo(3)];
> assert_eq!(join_all(futures).await, [1, 2, 3]);
> ```

Comment: This answer is a literal answer to the OP, and assumes that the futures you have are a bit more complicated than in the OP's example. If the point is to process an array/matrix concurrently, `rayon` would likely be more efficient than `n*m` futures.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @mcarton. Yes, the idea is to run a n*m matrix and update the values. More precisely I am trying to code a solver for a system of linear equations to be iteratively updated concurrently. That is why I would like the values to be updated in place.

Comment: Then I advise you to look at `rayon`, which is better suited for data-parallelism, while `async/await` is better suited for I/O concurrency.